# .attr() not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the user to change the text color, width, height etc of a `div` with a simple button click. I can't get this to work on a `div`.

However, if I have the exact same code put on an image instead of a `div`, it works.

Here's the little demo I'm working with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="mainButton">Click me</button>
        <div id="dummyText">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
            Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, 
            ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, 
            aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum 
            felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend 
            tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, 
            feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies 
            nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.
        </div>
        <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#mainButton").on('click' ,function(){
                    $('div').attr('width','500');
                    $('img').attr('width', '500');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It's probably something that I'm overlooking, but can't quite put my finger on it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `width` isn't an `attr` of `<div>`, it's a CSS value.

Comment: uses `$(selector).css('css-property', 'new value')`

Comment: FYI, when using `attr()` use `style`, e.g. `$('div').attr('style','width: 500px');`

Comment: @LGSon not sure why you'd do that when `css()` is available.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Just wanted to enlighten the OP that `attr()` target _an attribute_, which when it comes to inline style is `style` ... but of course, `css()` is generally a better way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to switch out `.attr` for `.css`

```
 $('div').css('width','500');

 $('img').css('width', '500');
```

https://codepen.io/MathiasaurusRex/pen/mKwGaz

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$('div').width(500);
$('img').width(500);
```

or:

```
$('div').css('width', '500px');
$('img').css('width', '500px');
```